# Generating increasing subsequences out of n numbers of length k

Tags: c, arrays, loops, recursion, subsequence

I want to generate all possible increasing subsequences of numbers (repetition allowed) from 1 to n, but of length k.
Ex. n=3, k=2
Output:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 2
2 3
3 3
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int s[100];
int n=6;
int k=4;

void subk(int prev,int index)
{
    int i;
    if (index==k)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
            printf("%d ",s[i]);

        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    s[index]=prev;
    for (i=prev; i<=n; ++i)
    {
        subk(i,index+1);//,s,n,k);
    }

}
int main()
{
    int j;
    for (j = 1; j<=n ; ++j)
    {
        subk(j,0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this generates some unwanted repetitions. How do I eliminate those?

Comment: Why use return statement in if condition??

Comment: `int s[100];` declared globally then `int s[4];` in `main()`. Why?

Comment: @Vijayraj S  ( 1, 1 ), ( 2, 2 ) and ( 3, 3 ) are not increasing subsequences.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, but I do require those subsequences as well

Comment: @AditiRawat sorry. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @rsp Gives something called "Bus error" on my mac if I don't give that

Comment: Why is 1,3 not in the output?

Comment: @Yunnosch missed it, sorry

Comment: @VijayrajS (1, 1) is an "increasing sequence", but not a "strictly increasing sequence".

Comment: Is using recursion required?

Comment: @Yunnosch I would prefer it, but if you have a Dynamic programming solution, I would love to read about it

Comment: Could you demonstrate the unwanted repititions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your code with `n = 3` and `k = 2` and got the following result:

```
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 2
1 2
1 3
2 2
2 2
2 3
3 3
```

This is obviously incorrect, as there are several identical numbers like `1 1` or `1 2`.

**But what exactly went wrong?**
Let's write down the right results if `n = 3` and `k = 3`. Now compare those to the result we got from the program when `n = 3` and `k = 2`.

```
    correct      program (incorrect)
    k = 3        k = 2
    1 1 1        1 1     
    1 1 2        1 1     
    1 1 3        1 1     
    1 2 2        1 2     
    1 2 3        1 2     
    1 3 3        1 3     
    2 2 2        2 2     
    2 2 3        2 2     
    2 3 3        2 3     
    3 3 3        3 3
```

Now we can see that the incorrect output of the program is the same as the first two columns of the correct answer when we set `k = 3`. This means that the program solves the problem for 3 columns if we set `k = 2`, but only displays the first two columns.

You need to stop the program from writing the same number several times.

## Solution 1

One way to do this is to execute the for-loop in the subk-function only once when it writes the last number (`index == (k - 1)`) into the buffer `s`. 
In order to achieve this, you need to add the following two lines to the end of your for-loop.

```
if (index == (k - 1))
    break;
```

(Instead of the *break* you could also use *return*)

After you added these two lines the function should look like this:

```
void subk(int prev, int index)
{
    int i;
    if (index == k)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<k; i++)
            printf("%d ", s[i]);

        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    s[index] = prev;
    for (i = prev; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        subk(i, index + 1);//,s,n,k);
        if (index + 1 == k)
            break;
    }

}
```

## Solution 2

Another way to solve the problem is to move the line `s[index] = prev;` to the beginning of the function and change the `k` in the if-statement to `k - 1`.
Now the function should look like this:

```
void subk(int prev, int index)
{
    int i;
    s[index] = prev;

    if (index == k - 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<k; i++)
            printf("%d ", s[i]);

        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    for (i = prev; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        subk(i, index + 1);//,s,n,k);
    }
}
```

With this solution, the for-loop is never executed when the `index` shows that the program is at the last 'sub-number'. It just displays the number and exits the function because of the return.

You get the right result with both solutions, but I personally like the second solution better, because there is no additional if-statement that is executed every iteration of the for-loop and the program is (slightly) faster.